# How to make a request on a view in a springboot repository

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jhipster

I am new in Jhipster and I would like to know what's wrong with my request :

SELECT  *  FROM
V_ALL
(where v_all is a view in the database )

I have made an entity which map the v_all view(in oracle)  with `@Immutable` annotation ,
I have made the ressource and  service
but when I try to execute the function it gives me these errors :

```
Failed to execute the query (the query above).
Column name not found could someone tells me what I missed .
```

I am sure the fields in my entity have the (column="") annotation to map them to a column in the view in oracle .
Is it the wrong way to do this request ? I would like to understand better and if there are other ways to make a request on a view using springboot ?
An **example** would be very fine for me thanks a lot

Comment: Could you post your full code especially entity and repository atleast and the full stack trace error log ?

Answer (score 0):

There is not really difference between views and table instead that you can't make a crud on a view so the main methods of the different steps of the view are in readOnly type also

The requests remain the same just by extending your repository to Repository or CrudRepository and You can then add any type of query you want native or jpql